# Equal code on equal input data has different output

Tags: python, collections

I have code

```
from collections import Counter
wr = [''.join(set(input())) for i in range(int(input()))]
wr = Counter(wr)
print(max(wr.values()))
```

And input data

```
8
disease
burned
viewer
praised
despair
burden
diapers
review
```

Output must be `3`, but sometimes output is `2`.

[proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JHOe.png)

How can I fix it?

---

Python 3.6.8

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want this code to do. I strongly recommend breaking it down a bit - it will be easier to debug. For example, are you sure the result of `''.join(set(input()))` is what you think it is? What about `wr`? Maybe print those things out so you can see them.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I'm pretty sure there must've been a typo somewhere, e.g. a space, making the set of characters different. If you do `set(input().strip())`, whitespace at the beginning and end of the string will be deleted (but not the whitespace in the middle).

Comment: Try printing out the value of `wr` after the list comprehension and after you put it in the `Counter`. The `set` is not an ordered collection so the letters will get mixed up, that's why sometimes it will have 2, sometimes 3 of the same string.

Comment: [this problem](https://csacademy.com/contest/interview-archive/task/anagrams/statement/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the call of `set` because it creates a non-ordered collection of the letters. By calling `sorted` on the set of unique letters an ordered list of unique letters will be created:

```
from collections import Counter
wr = [''.join(sorted(set(input()))) for i in range(int(input()))]
wr = Counter(wr)
print(max(wr.values()))
```

This produces the correct result now at every run.